# How to normalize colors between images that vary a lot in composition (from the command line)

Tags: image, filter, graphics, imagemagick, jpeg

I have 1000 images, all of which are in color. But some of them have a more sepia-ish look, others a vintage/pastel filter sort of thing, others a higher-contrast HDR type effect. Still others are cold/bluish, while some are more red or yellow or green. Some might be of night time, some of day, etc. Basically, they don't all have the same filter applied to them, so the colors don't quite feel balanced when looking at multiple images side-by-side.

Wondering how I can apply a filter to images in the terminal using some command-line tool like imagemagick to automatically normalize the colors of 1000 images, without requiring me to manually set the levels for each image.